# Proving Divorced Status

Tags: germany, marriage, divorce

I'm a US citizen but Nigeria is my home country. I married my German girlfriend in New York; we lived in Germany and divorced about 2 years ago.

Now I've relocated to Austria and I want to marry again but I don't have the Divorce certificate and no access to it.  What can I do so I can marry again?

How can I prove my divorce status legally ?

Comment: Apply for a new copy of the divorce certificate at the competent district or family court that issued the original divorce certificate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: Yeah it does help. I will. Thank you Sir

Comment: Did you divorce in Germany?

Comment: Yes. We divorced in Germany.

Answer (score 3):

Apply for a new copy of the divorce certificate at the competent district or family court that issued the original divorce certificate.

Depending on which family court is responsible, it may be possible to request a copy online:

- [Scheidungsnachweis online beantragen: alle Unterlagen und Kosten im Überblick - Antrag24.de](https://www.antrag24.de/c/scheidungsnachweis/)